# Networkx creating a graph from dictionary where dict shows the connections

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, networkx, edges

I have a dictionary, and I would like to create a networkx DiGraph with it. The dictionary shows the downstream nodes:

```
dict_ = {0: [1],
         1: [],
         2: [],
         3: [0, 1],
         4: [0, 1, 2]}
```

The important thing, here is `(1)` and `(2)` are end nodes, `(3)` is connected to `(1)` over `(0)`.

The graph should look like following:

```
1                2        ^    # digraph directions always to up
|                |        |
0____            |        |
|    |           |        |
3    |           |        |
     |___________|        |
     4                    |
```

How can I add edges in a way, it would respect my constraints? The algorithm should be somewhat generic, since I have a different dictionary for different situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have misunderstood the question but wouldn't a simple generator to unnest the list do the trick?

```
G = nx.from_edgelist(((n1, n2) for n1, l in dict_.items() for n2 in l),
                     create_using=nx.DiGraph)
```

Output graph:

[image]

Or, if the values in the dictionary are a path, maybe:

```
from itertools import pairwise

G = nx.from_edgelist(((n1, n2) for k, l in dict_.items()
                      for n1, n2 in pairwise((k, *l))),
                     create_using=nx.DiGraph)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The first picture is almost correct, however the connections between (1-3) and (1-4) should not exists. These connections are only possible over 0.

Comment: @oakca this is what my second code is doing. Then I don't understand what happens in `4: [0, 1, 2]`, shouldn't the edges be `4 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2`?

Comment: Glad the solution worked, if you have time I'd still be interested in knowing which approach worked and in updating the question/answer in case the output was not complete.

Comment: Well I formulated the question a little bit wrong. The issue is that the list are not really showing the path, instead they are showing the nodes which are downstream (meaning node 1 is approachable from node 3 via going over node 0, however there is no direct connection) from the node in question (meaning the key of the dictionary). I ended up writing an algorithm to filter the lists. For example after the algorithm the dictionary changed to `dict_ = {0: [1], 1: [], 2: [], 3: [0], 4: [0, 2]}` so that I can use your algorithm.